# how to store simulation data in hdf5?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I want to create an HDF5 file storing simulation data. The data consist of a stream of snapshots, which have identical (or very similar) format, but different simulation times. The idea is that upon reading the file one can search for snapshots in a given simulation-time interval.

How can this be accomplished in HDF5?

Clearly, one must use a `H5::Group` for each snapshot, which obviously must have distinct names (say 'snapshot1', 'snapshot2' etc). Can I add a `snapshot_name:time` table to the file for quick search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDF5 is self-describing data format, which means that the best way how to add information to each group is add attribute.

```
HDF5 "result.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   GROUP "Timestep_0" {
      ATTRIBUTE "Time" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F64LE
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
         DATA {
         (0): 0
         }
      }
      DATASET "Temperature" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F32LE
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 128, 128 ) / ( 128, 128 ) }
         DATA {
         (0,0): ...
```